# Can Winget uninstall multiple packages?

Tags: powershell, winget

How can one use winget to uninstall multiple packages at the same time?

---

My solution was repeat the command, like this:

```
winget uninstall --id "Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe" 
    && winget uninstall --id "Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: `uninstall-package app1,app2,app3` (msi in ps 5.1)

Answer (score 2):

[`winget uninstall`](https://aka.ms/winget-command-uninstall) only supports uninstalling *one* package at a time, so you'll have to make a call for *each* of the multiple packages you want to uninstall, which you can easily do with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (whose built-in alias is `%`, if you're looking for a shorter solution for interactive use):

```bash
'Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe', 'Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe' |
  ForEach-Object { winget uninstall --id $_ }
```

This will uninstall the specified packages *sequentially*.

While there are ways to run the uninstallation commands *in parallel*, notably with `ForEach-Object -Parallel` in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), doing so may cause interference between the uninstallation operations.